# External API GET() request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [IMDb API v2.0](http://www.imdbapi.com/) located here and I decided to test it. I can't. I think it's beacuse of cross-browser AJAX request from external sites.. but I don't know any other way. For example, here's a test at [imdbapi avatar](http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=Avatar)

See? Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


    <title>IMDB api</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#movie').keyup(function() {

       var yourMovie = $("#movie").val();
  $("#debug").append("You are searching for ... "+yourMovie+"\n");

dataString = "t=Avatar";

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/",
cache: false,
data: dataString,

success: function(html){
//$("#more").after(html);
alert("Success!");
}

});
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>


<form action="#" method="get" enctype="text/html" >
<input type="text" id="movie" maxlength="50" />

</form>

<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
<br />
<textarea id="debug" style="width: 500px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;font-face:typewriter;"></textarea><br />
<textarea id="more" style="width: 500px;height:150px;border:1px solid red;font-face:typewriter;"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using Google Chrome.

Here's what worked for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#movie').keyup(function() {

       var yourMovie = $("#movie").val();
  $("#debug").append("You are searching for ... "+yourMovie+"\n");

dataString = "callback=?&t=Avatar";

$.getJSON('http://www.imdbapi.com/', dataString, function(html){
//$("#more").after(html);
alert("Success!");
});


});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/",
cache: false,
data: dataString,

success: function(html){
//$("#more").after(html);
alert("Success!");
}
});
```

With

```
$.getJSON('http://www.imdbapi.com/?' + dataString, function(json_data){
alert(JSON.stringify(json_data));
});
```

Comment: yeah if you add datatype JSONP or ?callback=?

Answer (score 3):

It is a cross domain AJAX call, therefore you need a callback. jQuery makes this really easy, just add `?callback=?` to your url.

```
url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?" + dataString + "&callback=?"
```

Skip the `data = dataString` in this case, makes it easier (I find).

Try this, and continue on it further:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.imdbapi.com/?" + dataString + "&callback=?").success(function(data){
    console.log(data); // will contain all data (and display it in console)
})
```

This is the same as:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?"+dataString+"&callback=?",
dataType: 'JSONP'
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, it still doesn't work for me. I get it called off with undefined type: http://i.imgur.com/yWaF6.png

Answer (score 0):

You can run cross domain Ajax with jQuery. Set the `crossDomain` option at the call site:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> crossDomain(added 1.5)Boolean Default: false for same-domain requests,
>   true for cross-domain requests If you wish to force a crossDomain
>   request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of
>   crossDomain to true

**Edit-**

Actually, what exactly is your problem? I tried this and it returns Json properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/7VcUJ/

Response example:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Mon, 02 Apr
>   2012 22:28:14 GMT Content-Length: 618
>
> {"Title":"Avatar","Year":"2009","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"18 Dec
>   2009","Genre":"Action, Adventure, Fantasy, Sci-Fi","Director":"James
>   Cameron","Writer":"James Cameron","Actors":"Sam Worthington, Zoe
>   Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Michelle Rodriguez","Plot":"A paraplegic
>   marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn
>   between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his
>   home.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX320.jpg","Runtime":"2
>   hrs 42
>   mins","Rating":"8.1","Votes":"386930","ID":"tt0499549","Response":"True"}

Comment: Hmmm, it still doesn't work for me. I get it called off with undefined type: i.imgur.com/yWaF6.png

Answer (score 0):

Add a `callback` parameter to the URL to use JSONP:

```
dataString = "t=Avatar&callback=?";
```

Using a `$` will cause jQuery to auto-generate a callback function for you and handle the response automatically.

Recommended reading: [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp)